# Asp.net core 2.0 middleware - accessing config settings

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

In a asp.net core web api middleware, is it possible to access the configuration inside the middleware?  Can someone guide me how this is done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a `middle-ware` you can access settings. To achieve this, you need to get `IOptions<AppSettings>` in the `middle-ware` constructor. See following sample.

```cs
public static class HelloWorldMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHelloWorld(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<HelloWorldMiddleware>();
    }
}
    
public class HelloWorldMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly AppSettings _settings;
    
    public HelloWorldMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next, 
        IOptions<AppSettings> options
    )
    {
        _next = next;
        _settings = options.Value;
    }
    
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"PropA:{_settings.PropA}");
    }
}
    
public class AppSettings
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
}
```

For more information see [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204088/ASP-NET-Core-Configuration).