# Asp.net core 2.0 middleware - Use parameters from appsettings which changes on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, middleware

We need to do some work inside a middleware according to a parameter inside an appsettings.json. There parameter can change on runtime.

For that I can set reloadOnChange at settings file registration
     builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",
                            optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

This work in the case I use IOptionsSnapshopt inside a controller, because a controller is created per request. But a middleware is perlifetime.

I found [Asp.net core 2.0 middleware - accessing config settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722937/asp-net-core-2-0-middleware-accessing-config-settings) where is written how to access parameter from appsettings. --> But this works not if the parameter changes on runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation [ASP.NET Core Middleware: Per-request dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#per-request-dependencies)

> Because middleware is constructed at app startup, not per-request, scoped lifetime services used by middleware constructors are not shared with other dependency-injected types during each request. If you must share a scoped service between your middleware and other types, add these services to the `Invoke` method's signature. The `Invoke` method can accept additional parameters that are populated by dependency injection.

For example, instead of in the constructor, add `IOptionsSnapshot` parameter to `Invoke` method.

```
public static class HelloWorldMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHelloWorld(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<HelloWorldMiddleware>();
    }
}

public class HelloWorldMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public HelloWorldMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IOptionsSnapshopt<AppSettings> options)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"PropA: {options.Value.PropA}");
    }
}

public class AppSettings
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
}
```